# Angular orderBy filter in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use Angular filters from within a directive but I can't seem to work out what todo. I have:
`<tr ng-repeat="row in dataset | filter:searchon | orderBy:sorton ">`

I have the sorton as a isolated scope variable and change its value on click.

```
  .directive('gbsdatatable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      dataset: '=',
      searchon: '=',
      exportcsv: '=',
      pagination: '=',
      colmenu: '=',
      sorton: "="
    },
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/raff77/8CzsG/1/) - note the filter on line 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following as your template,

```
<tr ng-repeat=\"row in dataset | filter:searchon | orderBy:predicate:reverse \">
```

`predicate` here is the column name you want to order by.

`reverse` can be either true or false depending on its order.

You also need to bind `ng-click` to `<td>` elements inside `<thead>`

```
ng-click="predicate = 'comp'; reverse=!reverse"
```

On click, `predicate` is set to `comp` which is the name of column and `reverse` is set to `!reverse`.

[Working Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8CzsG/2/)

Comment: As a matter of interest, the ng-click will run in the parent scope. Will the ng-repeat be bound to the predicate and reverse variables? is there a way to set that from within the directive?

Comment: Strike that, got it. Its in the scope... duuuhh :)